# SQL Server: display merge of records by user in one row with condition

Tags: sql-server

I have the following table and need the following result with join based on username

[image: table and result]

Comment: What is your question here? What have *you* tried? Why didn't it work? Have you have look at the aggregate functions, which appears to be what you are after. Also, please don't post images of text; post text as text. Data is best served as DDL and DML statements, or at worst tabular formatted `text`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Query

```
select
  iif(count(*)>1, min(ID), max(right([User], 1))) ID,
  [User],
  iif(count(*)>1, concat('Total: (', cast(count(*) as varchar(12)), ')'), max(replace([Text], 'Text', 'Texto'))) [Text]
from
  MyTable
group by
  [User]
order by 1;
```

Results

```
ID  User    Text
1   User01  Total: (3)
2   User2   Texto 4
3   User3   Texto 5
6   User04  Total: (2)
```